# How to get object name inside class body?

Tags: c++

I created class Class and I want the function PrintObjectName to print out the object name.

By calling "SomeObject.PrintObjectName();" I'm expecting that console will print "SomeObject". How to achieve this?

````
class Class
{
public:
    PrintObjectName()
    {
        cout<<OBJECTNAME;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Class SomeObject;
    SomeObject.PrintObjectName();

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: You need to add a field into that class to hold object name (probably of `std::string` type) and fill it upon object creation.

Comment: Variable names are lost when the project is compiled. You can do that automatically. (You could achieve something close with macros though if you really wanted)

Comment: Okay, I created string to hold it's name, but what do you mean by "filling it upon object creation"? I know that I can create parametrizer constructor who will take name as a parametr but this is uneffective because I would be forced to write down the name of an object twice (one as a name of object, and second as a parametr for constructor)